# Making locally hosted server accessible ONLY by AWS hosted instances

Tags: security, amazon-web-services

Our system has 3 main components:

- A set of microservices running in AWS that together comprise a webapp.
- A very large monolithic application that is hosted within our network, and comprises of several other webapps, and exposes a public API that is consumed by the AWS instances.
- A locally hosted (and very large) database.

This all works well in production.

We also have a testing version of the monolith that is inaccessible externally.

I would like to able to spin up any number of copies of the AWS environment for testing or demo purposes that can access the demo testing version of the monolith. However, because it's a test system, it needs to remain inaccessbile to the public. I know how to achieve this with AWS easily enough (security groups etc.), but how can I secure the monolith so it can be accessed ONLY by any number of dynamically created instances running in AWS (given that the IP addresses are dynamic and can therefore not be whitelisted)?

The only idea I have right now is to use an access token, but I'm not sure how secure that is.

Edit - My microservices are each running on an EC2 instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are running your microservices on EC2, if you want API calls from your application servers running in AWS to come from a known IP/IPs then this can be accomplished by using a NAT instance or a proxy.  This way even though your application servers are dynamic, the apparent source of the requests is not.

For a NAT you would run your EC2 instances in a private subnet and configure them to send all of their Internet traffic out over the NAT instance which will have a constant IP.  Using a proxy server or fleet of proxy servers can be accomplished in much the same way, but would require your microservice applications be configured to use it.

---

The better approach would be to simply not send the traffic to your microservices over the public Internet.

This can be accomplished by establishing a VPN from your company network to your VPC.  Alternatively, you could establish a Direct Connect to bridge the networks.

---

*Side note, if your microservices are actually running in AWS Lambda then this answer does not apply.*